# The quote "keep looking up, that's the secret of life" is a statement or command?

Tags: grammar

how to classify this sentence, cause while it start out as a command, the intent is to state that "the secret of life is to keep looking up", so what is the correct way to classify that sentence.

Comment: It is a statement about a command. Or a statement about a recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

It's a command, called a *hortative*.

> urging to some course of conduct or action; exhorting; encouraging: *a hortatory speech.*

(From [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/hortative))

It is an imperative (lacking the *You* in *(You) keep looking up*.

The imperative *Keep looking up* is a hortatory, serving a function in the vein of "Make a plan to vote," "Maintain social distancing," or even the simple, "Let's go!"

Comment: A hortative is a special kind of command that features continuation rather than inception. They often use verbs like _keep, maintain,_ and _carry on_

Comment: 'Keep looking up' is an imperative construction, but (here) hortative (strongly encouraging) rather than domineering/commanding in intent. (Of course, the same sentence _could_ be used as an order.) // Twinning an imperative sentence with 'that's the secret ...' is strained grammar; one would expect 'Keeping one's head held high' say as the antecedent of 'that'.

Answer (score 0):

The clause "Keep looking up" is an [imperative](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/easy-learning/the-imperative), but the sentence as a whole is a [declarative](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/easy-learning/the-declarative), merely about that imperative.

Comment: Can imperative sentences typically function as antecedents for 'that'?

Comment: It's a clause functioning as an appositive.

Comment: To supply a linked and attributed authoritative reference, or not to supply a linked and attributed authoritatiove reference – that is the question.

Comment: You should post it as a question.